# How to set DB connection string username & password outside of Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to be able to restrict CRUD access for non-logged in users of a web application. This means I need to set the connection string after I have validated if they are a currently logged in user or not.

I have CRUD restrictions in my code, but want to put the account permissions in place to ensure users cannot access tables they are not supposed to access, or perform actions they are not supposed to perform.

Right now my connection string is set in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddDbContext<WorldContext>(options => options
    .UseMySql(_config["ConnectionStrings:Database"]));
```

How can I set the connection string, or at least the username & password for the DB account outside of startup? Sometime after I have validated that the user is logged in?

I am using `ASP.Net Core`, `Entity Framework Core`, and `Asp.NET Core Identity`.

---

I want to grant only the necessary permissions that the user will need. As quoted from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760(v=vs.110).aspx

> **Grant users only the necessary permissions in the data source.** A data source administrator should grant only the necessary permissions
>   to users. Even though Entity SQL does not support DML statements that
>   modify data, such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE, users can still access
>   the connection to the data source. A malicious user could use this
>   connection to execute DML statements in the native language of the
>   data source.

Comment: generally you restrict CRUD in your code, not in your DB for web apps.  Question is still valid in terms of how to do it, but not sure you should be doing it...

Comment: @KeithNicholas I've read over and over that you should use tiered DB accounts. Here on SO, at work, and in most DB/Web App security blogs/articles..etc. Each user doesn't get an account, but the queries ran from their actions are ran under a certain account. I'm sure that when you write  a comment on SO or Facebook your query is not executed as a DB Administrator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760(v=vs.110).aspx#General Security Considerations

Comment: sure, but why would your web app need rights to drop / create tables etc?  meaning you don't use an admin account.... just need selects, inserts, deletes updaes....   other than that, whats going to be different between your db connections?

Comment: @KeithNicholas It doesn't seem necessary to go into detail of what my web application is for, who and how it will be used, and what some users would need certain permissions and others would not. The short and accurate answer is that non-logged in users need only have `select` permissions, and only to certain tables. Logged in users need a variety of permissions, from read-only, to inserting and deleting, for certain tables only. There are more details under the hood, but my question should convey what I am trying to do, which is follow a security best-practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this but I would like to do it like this.

Create two `DbContext` one for user authentications and reading users database login details. Second for users which used to do CRUD operations on rest of the tables.

Question is how we register these two `DbContext` and where???

Here `Asp.net Core` Dependence Injection will did lots of work for us.

We can register the `LoginDbContext` in `Startup.cs` (as sample project did) which will used to validate the users and get there `DB` users login details.Also need to Inject `IServiceCollection` where we validate the users, So we can register the `CRUDDbContext` while creating connection string with user detail which we get from database. After that we can Inject the `CRUDDbContext` in controller or repository classes.

Comment: Can you provide code examples? This problem is mostly driven by what framework features I need to utilize to make this happen, and less about the theory of how it would function.

Comment: Please tell me about your login mechanism. After that I can help you about code as well.